# Mutation in Apollo Client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am using apollo client to perform an auto login with refresh token. The code I use is:

```
 const expirationTime = exp * 1000 - 60000;
if (Date.now() >= expirationTime) {
  await client //this is how user relogin
  .mutate({
    mutation: USER_LOGIN,
    variables: { rt: localStorage.getItem("refreshToken") },
  })
  .then((response) => console.log(response.data))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}
```

But I am not sure whether this is the right way, because my app seems to crash when I do this. I read the documentation for react but couldn't find anything other than useMutation

Comment: - How does it crash? - Where do you execute this code?

Comment: Page unresponsive

Comment: This is executed in index.js

Comment: Is there anything logged in the console?